# Issue With Semantic Token Highlighting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I came back from a several month long hiatus from code only to find that the colors for highlighting are weird and funky.

Here is what it's supposed to look like

[image: Highlight correct]

I updated my VSC and here is what it looks like now

[image: Highlight present day]

Both instances have Semantic Highlighting disabled, and if I were to enable it, it gets half of it right but not the other, and breaks other highlights

[image: Highlight with semantic enabled]

The latest version with it working fine as expected is version 1.65, although `console` becomes blue in that version, and it turns `Array`, `Boolean`, `Number` and `Object` among other type constructors to be colored like a regular variable starting at version 1.66.

I've done my research and kiinda found out why console broke but it still doesn't address the other issues

This link suggested I enable SH but then it turns my getters and setters into a variable and turns my expressions a different highlight than it was previously and my exports get highlighted to the type of the variable rather than it being a variable, as shown in above screenshots

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104616

I've tried to change it using regular tokenColorCustomization and regular textMate rules but since Semantic Highlighting takes priority.. it gets overwritten

I've also tried to make my own extension because some other thread said that the theme itself doesn't respect editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled, so I explicitly disabled it on the duplicate extension to no avail

Previously, simply disabling the semantic token highlighter would fix the issue but now it doesn't anymore and I'd really like not to be stuck on VSC 1.65 forever, so if anyone has any solutions that would be greatly appreciated.